# UrlHelper with ASP .Net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to be able to set up links in my webpages dynamically in ASP .Net Webforms. I know that you can set up routes dynamically in ASP .Net.

I want to generate Urls too from the RouteCollection in a similar way to the UrlHelper in ASP .Net MVC. So far I couldn't find anything that says if you can use the UrlHelper from ASP .Net MVC with Webforms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be interested in the **[FriendlyUrls Nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls)** which [Scott Hanselman recently blogged about](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWebFormsDynamicDataFieldTemplatesForDbGeographySpatialTypesPlusModelBindersAndFriendlyURLs.aspx), and [introduced in this blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx).

Code example:

```
<a href='<%# FriendlyUrl.Href("~/WebForms/Edit", Item.TouristAttractionId ) %>'>Edit</a>
```